# Problemas con array y conteo de registros

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy liado con un proyecto en Laravel 10 y me he quedado atascado con el conteo de registros de un array y no se como solventarlo. En primer lugar obtengo todos los registros de la tabla categorías exceptuando los de la categoría SUPERVISOR y a continuación compruebo si el usuario conectado tiene un rol en concreto y en tal caso realizo el conteo de los registros asociados por categoría. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Mi problema bien cuando el usuario no tiene el rol de Responsable, ya que solo debo contabilizar los registros asociados a las categorías que ese usuario tiene asignadas. Para ello, obtengo las categorías que ese usuario tiene asignadas pero no sé como añadir al array $categoriesCount[] el conteo de las categorías que tenga en este caso este usuario y el resto que se marquen como 0.

```
private function countComplaintsByCategory($user) {
    $categoriesCount = [];
    $categories = Category::all();

    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_name != "Supervisor") {
            $object = new stdClass;
            $object->id = $cat->id;
            $object->name = $cat->category_name;
            array_push( $categoriesCount, $object);
        }
    }
    
    if ($user->hasRole('Responsable')) {
        foreach($categoriesCount as $cat) {
            $count = Complaint::where('category_id', '=', $cat->id)->count();
            $cat->count = $count;
        }
    } else {
        $catuser = $user->categories;

    }
}
```

Comment: No entendí del todo cuál es el problema. Pero, ¿por qué seleccionas todo en vez de buscar los datos con los criterios específicos desde el principio? En la selección de todos para luego hacer un filtro posterior podrías estar haciendo trabajar al sistema innecesariamente en ciertos casos. A no ser que sí o sí necesites mostrar todas las categorías aunque el otro filtro no se cumpla ¿? Dado que no explicas con claridad el contexto, no podemos ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: Hola. El motivo es el siguiente. En primer lugar tengo que obtener todas las categorías existentes tengan o no registros asociados para pintar la tabla en la vista con la relación de categorías existentes. Luego lo que quiero hacer es obtener las categorías que un usuario tiene asociadas en concreto, contar los registros asociados a dichas categorías y añadir dicho valor al array que pinta el listado de categorías pero en cada caso solo mostrará el conteo de los registros asociados según el usuario. Igual el proceso que estoy realizando se puede simplificar mucho más.

Comment: Creo que faltan detalles en tu pregunta. Imaginando un contexto, mostrarías inicialmente todas las categorías, ya que dices que necesitas mostrarlas todas. Pero, ¿cómo se indica en ese contexto el usuario? Con el dato del usuario tú podrías hacer una nueva consulta para saber cuántas categorías asociadas tiene ese usuario. Por lo que dices en tu comentario, parecería que son dos cosas distintas (el total de categorías y las que un usuario tiene asociadas) que estás mezclando en tu lógica no sé por qué motivos ¿?

Comment: Correcto. Inicialmente muestro todas las categorías y después si el usuario no tiene un rol específico, obtengo sus categorías asignadas ($catuser = $user->categories;). Lo que quiero una vez tengo ambas cosas es reflejar el total de registros de las categorías del usuario en la tabla inicial.

Comment: Pues lo dicho. Haces la nueva consulta que obtiene el total de categorías que el usuario tiene asociadas y muestras ese valor en la tabla inicial. Partiendo de ahí. ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto?

Comment: Mi problema es que una vez que tengo la consulta con las categorías del usuario no sé como añadir en la lista de categorías ese valor

Comment: Simplemente tendrías que actualizar la **Vista**, agregando ese nuevo valor. Dado que no uso Laravel, ignoro el modo específico en que deberías hacerlo, pero, estando Laravel basado en Symfony, supongo que será relativamente fácil hacerlo. No sé si Laravel usa Ajax, o si puedes actualizar la vista mediante repositorios, como puedes hacer en Symfony.